# Select rows based on comparison with other rows in same view

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have a table which `x, y` points and need to find points where there are less than three other rows in the table with either a higher `x` value or higher `y` value.

```
  x  |  y  
-----+-----
  85 | 996
 109 | 989
 116 | 987
 164 | 983

         create or replace function sk(tableName text)
             returns integer
         as $$
         declare
            count integer;
            r record;

         begin
            count :=3;
            for r in execute 'select * from TABLE'
            if
                  loop
                  count := count - 1;

                  end loop;
                  return count;

         end
         $$ language plpgsql;
```

The expected result is a new view which has only those points which have less than 3 with greater `x` or `y`.

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Comment: "psql" is not a valid name for Postgres, that's the name of the standard command line interface. And you don't "need to loop", you need to solve a problem. Looping is one possible technique, and rarely an efficient approach in any RDBMS. I took the liberty to clarify a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Why do this in a function?  You can do this with a single query, such as:

```
select t.x, t.y, count(t2.x) as numBiggerXY
from t left join
     t2
     on t2.x > t.x or t2.y > t.y
group by t.x, t.y;
```

You can turn this into a flag:

```
select t.x, t.y, (count(t2.x) < 3) as biggerFlag
from t left join
     t2
     on t2.x > t.x or t2.y > t.y
group by t.x, t.y;
```

Comment: You work with 2 tables, but the question only mentions one. `GROUP BY` is missing and even if you add it, the query is not fit for possible duplicates on `(x,y)` unless you do more. Finally, it's `< 3` not `<= 3`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a PK column `id`, so this is the test case:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (id serial PRIMARY KEY, x int, y int);
INSERT INTO tbl(x,y) VALUES
  ( 85, 996)
, (109, 989)
, (116, 987)
, (164, 983);
```

If you have no PK, create one. Else you have to use other techniques in the query to distinguish possible duplicates on `(x,y)` - which have not been ruled out.

```
SELECT t.*, count(t2.x) AS ct_greater
FROM        tbl t
LEFT   JOIN tbl t2 ON t2.x > t.x OR t2.y > t.y
GROUP  BY t.id
HAVING count(t2.x) < 3;
```

Empty result for the test case because there are always 3 other rows with bigger `x` or bigger `y`.